# Going back with ActionBar

Tags: android, back

The following code only works when i set `android.`R.id.home
Does anyone know why? I think a few minutes ago it worked without..

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ID `android.R.id.home` is set automatically by android to the up button. I cannot image that it could have worked with another ID, given you haven't added custom views to your `ActionBar` or stuff like that.

All IDs on `R.id.*` are the ones you assigned yourself, the ones in `android.R.id.*` are predefined IDs by android for some basic stuff (for example the `ListView` in a `ListActivity` would have the ID `android.R.id.list`)

The code you posted is pretty much standard and absolutely correct.

Comment: minus the lack of else/if statements

Comment: thanks! @tyczj thats true, it was just for testing purposes. I won't leave it like that

Comment: Don't see a need for them tbh. Could you elaborate on what advante using else if would have here in your opinion?

Comment: is it possible to build a Ressource with a variable? Like `...(R.string.myString_i)`? i = var in a loop, results in myString_1, myString_2, ...

Comment: Of course it is, but if / else won't help you there either, it's just a matter of the order of your if / else statements then ... which matches your resource id first will 'win'.